# I get error when trying to use HardDelete() in boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have table Entity which is connected to many tables. I set up on every relationship cascade delete. I also use boilerplate soft delete on table Entity first. Then I try to use HardDelete() to delete entity permanently.  Here is code:

```
public async Task DeletePermanently(int id)
    {
        CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.SoftDelete);

        var entity = await _entityRepository.GetAsync(id);
        await _entityRepository.HardDeleteAsync(entity);

    }
```

This is error that I get:

```
SqlException: The Database ID 14, Page (1:2119), slot 0 for LOB data type node does not exist. This is usually caused by transactions that can read uncommitted data on a data page. Run DBCC CHECKTABLE.
```

I try also DBCC CHECKDB, and don't get any error.

Comment: Did you run `dbcc checktable` as the message suggests? Regardless, this is a data corruption issue and we can't fix that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a data corruption issue.

Comment: I also run dbcc checktable, and don't get any error.